# Twilio `$client->account->sms_messages->create()` not working, just loading page

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, twilio, twilio-php

```
$to=+11111111;   
$body="hello Its not working";  

    $AccountSid = "*********************************";
    $AuthToken = "*********************************";

    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    $from = '+11111111';
    $message =     $client->account->sms_messages->create($from, $to, $body);

    return true;
```

It is working on normal server but not on amazon server.
when i comment `$message` the code loads the page properly and when uncomment the `$message`, it just keeps on loading (i.e. the loading circle keeps on rolling not opens any page).
I am receiving both the numbers and the text message too  thats not an issue but the `$client->account->sms_messages->create()` not working.

Someone help!

Comment: It is resolved. working now. some port issue was there!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the detailed solution for reference?

Comment: sure. it was the port issue. the port on server was not opened. due to which it was not sending message.

Answer (score 0):

If you give "+11111111111" as from number. Twilio will show the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The 'From' number 11111111111 is not a valid phone number or shortcode.
```

So you should add valid twilio number that exist in your twilio account as from number. Then try this.

```js
$sms = $client->account->messages->create(array( 
        'To' => "$toNumber", 
        'From' => "$myNumber",
        'Body' => "$msg"));   
}
```

Comment: I added proper numbers. it was some port access issues but thanx for suggestion